# How can I create a listener for a specific property of a recoil state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, recoiljs

Is there a way to create a listener for an specific property of an state object?
Let's do an example:

```
type ExampleAtomProperties = {
  id: number;
  description: string;
};

const ExampleAtom = atom<
  ExampleAtomProperties>({
  key: "ExampleAtom",
  default: {id: 1, description: "Description"},
});

const Component = () => {
  const [exampleAtomObject, setExampleAtomObject] = useRecoilState(ExampleAtom);

  const setDescription = () => {
    setExampleAtomObject({...exampleAtomObject, description: "new description"});
  }

 const setId = () => {
    setExampleAtomObject({...exampleAtomObject, id: 2});
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(exampleAtomObject);
  }, [exampleAtomObject]);

  return (
   <>
    <Button onClick={setDescription}> Set Description </Button> 
    <Button onClick={setId}> Set ID </Button> 
   </>
  );
}
```

So, with this implementation, this component is re-render after setting any property of the state object.

I need that when the *description* is updated this component be rendered, and not if the *id* property changed.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you update state property without rerender the component by updating via reference, although it is not recommended. i hope this would be the same with recoil js. let me know if there's any error with recoil js and i will delete this answer right away.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [ex, setEx] = useState({ id: 1, description: "test" });

  const setDescription = () => {
    setEx({ ...ex, description: "new description" });
  };

  const setId = () => {
    ex.id++;
  };

  const log = () => {
    console.log(ex);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rendered!!!", ex);
  }, [ex]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setDescription}> Set ex's Description </button>
      <button onClick={setId}> Set ex's ID </button>
      <button onClick={log}>console.log ex object</button>
      <br/>
      <pre>ex = &#123; id: {ex.id}, description: {ex.description} &#125;</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```